# Redacting a SSN on form display under Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-encrypted

I have a Rails 4 application and I am using the [`attr_encrypted`](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) gem to store SSN in an encrypted form in the DB.

What I am trying to do is only display the last 4 digits when editing / showing the form. So essentially once the SSN has been saved, users can't see the full SSN in the form. So I've tried doing the following,

```
class PaymentData < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_encrypted :ssn, key: 'secret'

  alias_method :org_ssn, :ssn
  def ssn
    org_ssn.reverse # just a way of testing if this works
  end
end
```

What I am seeing that the on the show form, which uses `<%= @payment_data.ssn %>`, it works fine. But on my edit form which is using `<%= f.input :ssn %>`, the edit field is prepopulated with the full SSN.

Note: I am using the [`simple_form`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem for my forms, but if I use the basic, `<%= f.text_field :ssn %>` syntax, I see the same full SSN.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you store and encrypt the full and partials SSNs separately? Then just render the partial SSN when needed.

Comment: @claptimes, I have considered that, but you would need to figure out how to display one field and submit to a completely different one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing,

```
def obfuscated_ssn
  return ssn unless ssn && ssn.size > 3
  ssn.last(4).rjust(ssn.length, '*')
end

def obfuscated_ssn=(ssn)
  self.ssn = ssn unless ssn.include?('*')
end
```

This is a bit hacky, but it displays the SSN with a redacted string, but then doesn't save a string with the redacted bits, `*`, to keep bad data from getting the database.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something different.

Keep your `obfuscated_ssn` method from your answer, it makes sense to have it in the model. However overriding the setter like this... well I'd go a different way.
What I don't really like, is that you are doing validations in the setter. I checked the gem page but couldn't find anything related to validation, but normally your model would include validation rules like

```
validates_length_of :ssn, :minimum => 5, :maximum => 20, :allow_blank => true
```

I don't know if the ssn gem is clever enough to run the validations only on non-encrypted data though...

But anyway here's how I would tweak your form/controller :

**Your form**

> you would need to figure out how to display one field and submit to a completely different one

I suggest changing the default value shown by the field (Ruby doc for text_[field](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field) :)

```
f.text_field(:ssn, :value => f.object.obfuscated_ssn)
```

Now I'm not sure about the behavior you want. Is the user supposed to always write the ssn field? Or do you want to leave it unchanged in case the user doesn't enter anything ? If so I'd put some checks on your controller

**Controller**

```
def model_params
  if params[:your_model][:ssn] == @model.obfuscated_ssn
    params[:your_model].delete(:ssn) # Make sure your model doesn't get updated with obfuscated ssn
  end
  params.require(:your_model).permit(:ssn, etc.)
end
```